# Third isomorphsim theorem(Utilization)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In my note and book there are questions that doesn't have any solution for a Third isomorphism thm

$Q)$ Find the ring which is isomorphic with the $R / I$

$(1)$ $R = \mathbb{Z}[x], I= \langle 2, x^2+1\rangle$. (Hint ;  third isomorphsim thm)

$(2)$ $R = \mathbb Z[\sqrt -5], I = \langle 1+\sqrt-5 , 3\rangle$

So my solution is

$(1)$ $R / I \simeq (\mathbb{Z}[x] / \langle x^2+1\rangle) /  (I / \langle x^2+1\rangle) \color{red}{\simeq}  (\mathbb{Z}[i] / \langle 2\rangle) \simeq \mathbb{Z_2}(i)  $ (Here the $i$ is the  root of the $x^2+1$)

$(2)$ $R / I \simeq (\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt-5] / \langle 1 + \sqrt-5\rangle) / (I / \langle 1 + \sqrt-5 \rangle) \color{red}{\simeq}  (\mathbb{Z}_6 / \langle 3\rangle) \simeq \mathbb{Z_3} $

It depends on only my intuition, So I can't sure my method true or not because of the red part.

Therefore, my questions are

First) In my thought despite of the $X_1 /Y \simeq Z_1$ and $X_2 /Y \simeq Z_2$, We can't say $X_1 / X_2 (\simeq (X_1 /Y) / (X_2 /Y))  \simeq Z_1 / Z_2$.

(Here $X_1$ and $X_2$ are groups(or rings) Also $Y \lhd X_i$ )

Because Focusing the question $(2)$ case, I can't sure  $\langle 2\rangle \subset \mathbb{Z}_6$.

Is my thought right?

Second) Are my solutions  right? (Still I have a doubt for the red parts.) Could you explain why does it true or not for me? If my solution are incorrect, Please let me know correct method.

Any help always appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Note that over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $x^2 + 1 = (x + 1)^2$. So for (1), try modding out by $2$ first, then by $x^2 + 1$. For (2), can you write $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ as a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? Once you do that, you can simplify the ideal corresponding to $I$.

Comment: @RichardD.James, would you give me some more hints about the (2)?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}] \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x^2 + 5)}$. What does the $I$ correspond to under this isomorphism? This is kind of using the third isomorphism theorem "backwards".